# Unable to remove file handle on windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have a file on a windows share which is locked. I cannot move or delete the file.

I found the file handle with ProcessExplorer and tried to delete it. Unfortunately I get the error messeage:

```
Error opening process: Das Handle ist ungültig.
```

The guilte process is the `System` process. Guess it's not a god idea to kill this process.

Any ideas how to release the lock on the file without restarting the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried releasing the handle using `Share and Storage Management`?

Start -> Administrative Tools -> Share and Storage Management

[image: Share and Storage Management]